# How do you find a matching IDL instruction using the Anchor instruction discriminator from instruction data?

Tags: anchor, base58

How are the first 8 bytes (discriminator) on instruction data determined for an anchor instruciton? If I have the idl what's the best way to use instruction data to find which instruction in the IDL it is?

I'm seeing random bytes like 51, 179, 232, 242

Answer (score 9):

You have to get the first 8 bytes of the sha256 hash of the `global:[instruction_name]`.

From the [anchor source](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/2a07d841c65d6f303aa9c2b0c68a6e69c4739aab/lang/syn/src/codegen/program/common.rs#L9-L23)

```
// Namespace for calculating instruction sighash signatures for any instruction
// not affecting program state.
pub const SIGHASH_GLOBAL_NAMESPACE: &str = "global";

// We don't technically use sighash, because the input arguments aren't given.
// Rust doesn't have method overloading so no need to use the arguments.
// However, we do namespace methods in the preeimage so that we can use
// different traits with the same method name.
pub fn sighash(namespace: &str, name: &str) -> [u8; 8] {
    let preimage = format!("{}:{}", namespace, name);

    let mut sighash = [0u8; 8];
    sighash.copy_from_slice(&crate::hash::hash(preimage.as_bytes()).to_bytes()[..8]);
    sighash
}
```

The same logic applies to the [8 byte discriminator for accounts](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/lang/attribute/account/src/lib.rs#L93-L107), you take the first 8 bytes of the sha256 hash of `account:[AccountStructName]`